# creating an alias after row's computations?

Tags: mysql, sql

there's a way to create an alias after some computation?

in practice there is a better way to write this:

```
select
    case when aaa ... then then else end AS ALIAS1,
    case when bbb ... then then else end AS ALIAS2,
    case when ccc ... then then else end AS ALIAS3,
    /* the sum of previous aliases */
    case when aaa ... then then else end +
    case when bbb ... then then else end +
    case when ccc ... then then else end AS ALIAS_SUM
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. That way you are not dealing with the cases twice.

```
SELECT *, ALIAS1 + ALIAS2 + ALIAS3 AS ALIAS_SUM
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN aaa ... THEN ... ELSE END AS ALIAS1,
        CASE WHEN bbb ... THEN ... ELSE END AS ALIAS2,
        CASE WHEN ccc ... THEN ... ELSE END AS ALIAS3
    FROM...
) AS casequeries
```

Comment: if i have a join in the main SELECT, i have to do it in the inner SELECT too?

Comment: Basically, you can do everything in the subquery, and then just do the addition on the outside query...so JOINs on the inside arent really needed on the outside

Comment: yup but what about the same join executed twice? it will be twice slow

Comment: But, you dont have a need for that join twice. You can do everything in your subquery, and just spit it out...adding whatever you want on the outside

Comment: lot of pain here because in the inner query the outer aliases are not available... then my inner query should contain joins, the outer not... is this right? thank you a lot!